# very simple Wireshark connect monitor

Tags: wireshark

I would like to have an extremely simple ip and timestamp log of "connects" to my ubuntu server.

It should only be "me" from a handful of known locations.

I would like to see this and confirm it is as boring as I hope.

Comment: The `tcpdump` command can make a packet capture, that you can later analyze with Wireshark.

Comment: ... or even `tcpdump` alone can do like `sudo tcpdump -ni any -Q in -tttt port 22 or port 443` ... Notice how you specify the ports `port 123 or port 456 or port 789 ...` etc.